# What is the Best way to load jQuery custom JS file in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Basically I had a static page using many jQuery dom manipulation for creating UI and initiating few plugins. But now Im moving with AngularJs.

orignally I had main.js

```
  (function($){
    var somedom = $('#someid');
somedom.callingManyJquery() plugins

...some other jquery dom code
  })(jQuery);
```

And now I have my controller, which takes care of rendering HTML content main.html into index.html. But I want to load the above main.js into a Directive or as a service so DOM manipulations should happen only after controller loads then HTML and jQuery will be able to find my HTML tags to catch the DOM.

inside index.html I have

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

in app.js I have routes and config.

```
.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
      })
```

What should be the best way to load my jQuery files into my AngularJs controllers.

Comment: In most cases, the best way to use jQuery in Angular is to not use it at all -- they tend to interfere with each other. That said, if you just search Google for "jquery angular", you should find a few guides to steer you through it.

Comment: Currently im loading it as Directives.

Comment: Actually Im using many jQuery plugins like Parralax, WOW slider, Loader, DatePicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created separate Directive and added all page jquery scripts into 'mainDom' directive and attached it to the page where I want to load them.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to wrap your jQuery logic in an Angular service or an Angular factory. In the future you can easily move your jQuery DOM manipulation in Angular directives.